# FreeMarker : a character is not recognized

Tags: replace, freemarker

I'm using the function replace in a freemaker template like this:

```
example?replace("<|>|_|!", ' ', 'r')
```

The character '<' is not replaced. It can work with this ( I can't explain it=:

```
example?replace('<', ' ')
```

Any help ?

Thank you :)

Comment: I have tried that on https://try.freemarker.apache.org/ and it works there. Could you double check this?

Comment: I tried but I have the same issue, maybe I'm not using the function in a good way ; Template : `<m>${m?replace('\\|<|!|\\"|>|', ' ', 'r')}</m>` . Data model : `m = a<a>a`. Result : `<m> a < a  a </m>`

Comment: This is not the same as in your question... here you start the string with `\\|`, so it will look for `|<`, not just `<`.

Comment: The error was the escaping backslash. To escape the backslash we use `\\\\\`. Thanks again : )

Comment: You can avoid double escaping if you start the string literal with `r`: `r'\\|<|etc'`. Also, `"` need not be escaped in Java regular expressions.